# main.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')

Tags: angular

I have an angular project that is being built with the command:

```
`npm run start`
```

which runs the script:

```
`"start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --prod",`
```

When the app is opened in "http://localhost:4200" it seems to load ok, but as soon as I change the user using the command:

```
`_setUser(window._user.sally_superAdmin);`
```

The user info is returned but I get an error message in the console:

```
main.js:1 ERROR Malformed UTF-8 data
    rc @ main.js:1
    handleError @ main.js:1
    next @ main.js:1
    __tryOrUnsub @ main.js:1
    next @ main.js:1
    _next @ main.js:1
    next @ main.js:1
    next @ main.js:1
    emit @ main.js:1
    main.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
        at a.project (main.js:1:4756133)
        at a._next (main.js:1:3551188)
        at a.next (main.js:1:3529941)
        at a._next (main.js:1:3551286)
        at a.next (main.js:1:3529941)
        at h._next (main.js:1:3557774)
        at h.next (main.js:1:3529941)
        at h._next (main.js:1:3530167)
        at h.next (main.js:1:3529941)
        at h._next (main.js:1:3560273)
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting the TypeError problem or even where to start looking. Has anyone any ideas?

I debugged the line in main.js (which is autogenerated via angular) and I get to this line of code. I just don't know where to look from here?

```
let i = (()=>{
            class f {
                constructor(g) {
                    this.http = g,
                    this.documents = [],
                    this.resource = "help"
                }
                query(g=!1) {
                    return this.http.get(`${this.resource}/query`).pipe((0,
                    o.q)(1), (0,
                    a.U)(v=>v.help), (0,
                    a.U)(v=>g ? v : v.filter(d=>"deleted" !== d.status)))
                }
                save(g) {
                    return this.http.post(`${this.resource}/save`, g).pipe((0,
                    a.U)(v=>v.help))
                }
                remove(g) {
```